# How to use the Polars library in Python to find consecutive 1s?

Tags: python-polars

Here is a piece of code for Polars library along with some test data:

```
import polars as pl

data = {'test': [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]}
df = pl.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to achieve the following result:

```
[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

**The desired result is to keep the original 0 values unchanged, start accumulating the consecutive 1s, and reset the count to the initial value when encountering a 0 value.**

The end result is still data of type pl.DataFrame.

The amount of data is so large that a syntax similar to a for loop cannot be used.

What should I do if I am required to use only polars functions and not numpy or other libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to break up the output data is that it is a cumulative count by group, with a new group starting every time a 0 appears in the input data. In that way you can build the following expression:

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("test")
    .cumcount()
    .over(pl.when(pl.col("test") == 0).then(1).cumsum().forward_fill())
)
```

The `cumsum` in the `over` expression on a flat `1` literal column, along with filling the `null`s appropriately, creates the groups we need.