# How to use the Polars library in Python to incrementally tag consecutive 1s?

Tags: python-polars

How do I go about tagging the consecutive occurrence of 1s in a dataset using Polars? I found a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76085890/how-to-use-the-polars-library-in-python-to-find-consecutive-1s) answered. I am trying to tag the data with a unique integer identifier to later do a groupby or pivot. I will use the same sample data as the referenced question.

```
import polars as pl

data = {'Switch': [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]}
df = pl.DataFrame(data)
```

Output wants to be

```
shape: (33, 2)
┌────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ Switch ┆ Switch Event Number │
│ ---    ┆ ---                 │
│ i64    ┆ u32                 │
╞════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 1      ┆ 1                   │
│ 1      ┆ 1                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 1      ┆ 2                   │
│ 1      ┆ 2                   │
│ 1      ┆ 2                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 1      ┆ 3                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 1      ┆ 4                   │
│ 1      ┆ 4                   │
│ 1      ┆ 4                   │
│ 1      ┆ 4                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 1      ┆ 5                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 1      ┆ 6                   │
│ 1      ┆ 6                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 1      ┆ 7                   │
│ 1      ┆ 7                   │
│ 1      ┆ 7                   │
│ 1      ┆ 7                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 1      ┆ 8                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 1      ┆ 9                   │
└────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

I am new to Polars and basically lost.

Comment: Should the last row not be `1, 9` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polars recently added run-length-encoding functions for these types of problems.

Here we can use [`rle_id()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rle_id.html)

```
df.with_columns(
   pl.when(pl.col("Switch") == 1).then(pl.col("Switch").rle_id())
)
```

```
shape: (33, 1)
┌────────┐
│ Switch │
│ ---    │
│ u32    │
╞════════╡
│ null   │
│ 1      │
│ 1      │
│ null   │
│ 3      │
│ 3      │
│ 3      │
```

We can use a [dense rank](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rank.html#polars.Expr.rank) to re-number the ids and then fill in the nulls.

```
df.with_columns(
   pl.when(pl.col("Switch") == 1).then(pl.col("Switch").rle_id())
     .rank("dense")
     .fill_null(0)
     .alias("Switch Event Number")
)
```

```
shape: (33, 2)
┌────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ Switch ┆ Switch Event Number │
│ ---    ┆ ---                 │
│ i64    ┆ u32                 │
╞════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 1      ┆ 1                   │
│ 1      ┆ 1                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 1      ┆ 2                   │
│ 1      ┆ 2                   │
│ 1      ┆ 2                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 1      ┆ 3                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 1      ┆ 4                   │
│ 1      ┆ 4                   │
│ 1      ┆ 4                   │
│ 1      ┆ 4                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 1      ┆ 5                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 1      ┆ 6                   │
│ 1      ┆ 6                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 1      ┆ 7                   │
│ 1      ┆ 7                   │
│ 1      ┆ 7                   │
│ 1      ┆ 7                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 1      ┆ 8                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 0      ┆ 0                   │
│ 1      ┆ 9                   │
└────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks @jqurious for responding so quickly. I was on ver 0.18.4. Did 'pip install polars upgrade' and it started working.